# Initialize values in Model asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a Asp.net application in Visual studios in my model I have this class

```
public class Goalkeeper
{     
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static string Position { get; set; }
    public static int Matches { get; set; }
    public static int Cleansheets { get; set; }        
}
```

Is there a way for me to set the values of these in the model so I can use thme in all my different views and controller actions so I dont have to set them like this for example (Goalkeeper.Matches = 234;) In every single action in my controller, because that seems very inefficient.

Comment: public int Matches {get{return this.Matches;} set{this.Matches= 234;}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

Add a constructor to your Model, where you set the initial values:

```
public class Goalkeeper
{
    public Goalkeeper() {
        Position = "Goalkeeper";
        Matches = 5;
        Cleansheets = 0;
    }

    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static string Position { get; set; }
    public static int Matches { get; set; }
    public static int Cleansheets { get; set; }
}
```

Or, initialize the properties directly:

```
public class Goalkeeper
{ 
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static string Position { get; set; } = "Goalkeeper";
    public static int Matches { get; set; } = 5;
    public static int Cleansheets { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Wondering how to Initialize the Goalkeeper class with multiple registers.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo you can create multiple constructors. For example `public Goalkeeper(string name, string position) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of C# you are using you can initialize the property like this:

```
public static string Name { get; set; } = "Whatever";
```

This only works in C# 6 though